# wordpress need more custom text containers on template but how

Tags: wordpress, containers

So I have made a template for a page. Works great.

But How would I add more text areas for the page? When I edit the page I have one large text area (in the backend) where I can edit text. This is awesome but I need more. I would like to be able to place containers around the template restricting the editor to only changing the text on the page and not having to edit text inside a lot of html in the editor.

Like

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div>container1</div>
some more html
<div>container2</div>
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at adding in some metaboxes to the post admin area.

If you want to use a plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/

If you want roll your own: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

And here is a good tutorial that wraps it all up: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tag/wordpress-meta-box/

Comment: Thanks Dale. Meta boxes is just the thing I was looking for.